# How to solve the given integral avoiding infinite series sum?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

**Question:** How to solve the following integral?
$$I = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{N_a + N_b - 1}}{(p \Omega_1 + \Omega_2 x)^{N_a + 1}} \ln (1 + Qx) \, _2F_1\left( N_b + 1, N_b; N_b +1; \dfrac{-\Omega_3}{\Omega_4}x\right)dx, \tag{1}$$
where $N_a, N_b \in \mathbb Z_+$ and $\Omega_1, \Omega_2, \Omega_3, \Omega_4, p, Q \in \mathbb R_+$. I am looking for a closed-form solution for the above integral. A solution in terms of any special function will also be good enough.

Any leads appreciated.

**My attempt:** Representing $\log(1 + Qx)$ in terms of Meijer's $G$ function, we have 
\begin{align}
 I = {} & \, \Omega_2^{-(N_a + 1)}\int_0^{\infty}x^{N_d + N_b - 1}\left( x + \dfrac{p\Omega_1}{\Omega_2}\right)^{-(N_a + 1)}G_{2, 2}^{1, 2}\left( Qx \left\vert \begin{smallmatrix} 1, & 1\\ 1, & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right) \\ 
& \hspace{6cm}\times\, _2F_1\left( N_b + 1, N_b; N_b +1; \dfrac{-\Omega_3}{\Omega_4} x\right) \, dx \tag{2}
\end{align}
A solution to (2) exists in [[1, eqn. 2.2]](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/some-integrals-involving-gausss-hypergeometric-function-and-meijers-g-function/3CB3ED1DA427C7A2A234C273BE62D4B5), resulting into infinite series summation.

Can anyone suggest any **alternate solution that doesn't contain infinite series sum?**

Comment: That is one scary-looking integral. +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate way to solve. 
\begin{align}
 & \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{N_a + N_b - 1}}{(p \Omega_1 + \Omega_2 x)^{N_a + 1}} \ln(1 + Qx) \, _2F_1\left( N_b + 1, N_b,; N_b +1 , \dfrac{-\Omega_3}{\Omega_4}x\right)dx \\
= & (p\Omega_1)^{-(N_a + 1)} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{N_a + N_b - 1} \left( 1 + \dfrac{\Omega_2}{p\Omega_1} x\right)^{-(N_a + 1)} \ln(1 + Qx) \, _2F_1\left( N_b + 1, N_b,; N_b +1 , \dfrac{-\Omega_3}{\Omega_4}x\right)dx \\
= & \dfrac{1}{(p\Omega_1)^{(N_a + 1)} \Gamma(N_a + 1)\Gamma(N_b)} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{N_a + N_b - 1} G_{1, 1}^{1, 1} \left( \left.\dfrac{\Omega_2}{p\Omega_1} x\right\vert \begin{smallmatrix} -N_a \\ 0\end{smallmatrix}\right) G_{2, 2}^{1, 2} \left( Qx \left\vert \begin{smallmatrix} 1, & 1 \\ 1, & 0\end{smallmatrix} \right.\right) G_{2, 2}^{1, 2} \left( \left.\dfrac{\Omega_3}{\Omega_4}x \right\vert \begin{smallmatrix} -N_b, & 1 - N_b \\ 0, & -N_b\end{smallmatrix}\right)dx, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where the second term inside the integral is represented as a Meijer's G function using [1, Section IV-C], the log function is represented as a Meijer's G function using [2, below Fig. 1] and the Gauss hypergeometric function is represented as a Meijer's G function using [3, eqn. (17)]. **The closed-form solution to (1) is now straightforward to represent using [4](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.21.0081.01), in terms of extended generalized bivariate Meijer’s G function (EGBMGF).**

**Note:** Looking for some expert comments/opinions.

[[1]. I.S. Ansari, et.al., "Impact of Pointing Errors on the Performance of Mixed RF/FSO Dual-Hop transmission Systems".](https://repository.kaust.edu.sa/bitstream/handle/10754/269854/arxiv.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

[[2]. P.S. Bithas, "Digital Communications over Generalized-K Fading Channels"](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Petros_Bithas2/publication/4197200_Digital_Communications_over_Generalized-K_Fading_Channels/links/02e7e51d95c312a149000000.pdf)

[[3]. V.S. Adamchik, et.al. "The algorithm for calculating integrals of Hypergeometric type functions and its realization in REDUCE system"](https://sci-hub.tw/https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=96930)

[[4]. http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.21.0081.01](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.34.21.0081.01)

Answer (score 3):

**Too long for a comment**. The hypergeometric function inside the integral is actually elementary because of parameters: $_2F_1(\ldots)=\left(1+\frac{\Omega_3}{\Omega_4}x\right)^{-N_b}$. The integral can therefore be reduced to the form
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\alpha+x}\right)^{N_a+1}\left(\frac{x}{\beta+x}\right)^{N_b}\frac{\ln(1+Qx)}{x^2}\,dx=\tag{1}\\
=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1+\alpha y)^{-N_a-1}(1+\beta y)^{-N_b}\ln(1+Qy^{-1})\,dy.\tag{2}
\end{align}

- Now, if $N_a$, $N_b$ were arbitrary (admissible) complex numbers and if we could replace $\ln(1+Qx)$ by $(1+Qx)^s$ with some $s$, then the integral could be expressed in terms of [Lauricella function $F_D^{(2)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauricella_hypergeometric_series#Integral_representation_of_FD). When we have logarithm instead, we could write the result as a derivative of this function w.r.t. to parameter $s$ evaluated at $s=0$.
- For arbitrary but fixed integer $N_a$, $N_b$ the integrals (1)-(2) look computable to me (e.g. doing partial fraction expansion first). I would not expect something more complicated than dilogarithms. Moreover for $\alpha=\beta$ the result is clearly an elementary function (integration by parts).

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. I am trying to solve by your way. Shouldn't there be a "-" (minus) sign in (2) as once you replace $1/x = y$ then $-dx/x^2 = dy$?

Comment: @NashJ. No, the minus is absorbed by the exchange of integration bounds.

Comment: Oh yes. My Bad!

Comment: Can you please give your comments for the solution I posted? Thanks!

Comment: @NashJ. I am not very familiar with Meijer functions. I think of them as being essentially hypergeometric functions or some degenerations thereof, so your answer sounds consistent with what I wrote on Lauricella. But this is just an impressionistic view.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this.